# aside element with ID

Tags: html, css, element

I'm looking to display a tour itinerary within an aside element with the ID `tour_itinerary`, with each h1 element nested within having the font-size 1.2em, each h2 element nested within having the font-size 0.9em, and each paragraph nested within having the font-size 0.8em.

This is my code so far (it hasn't been effective yet):

```css
aside#tour_itinerary h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

aside#tour_itinerary h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

aside#tour_itinerary p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
  
  <header>
     <h1>Itinerary</h1>
  </header>
   <aside id="tour_itinerary">

  <h2>Day 1</h2>
  <p>We start from the foothills above Littleton, Colorado, 
     promptly at 9am. The first day is a chance to get 
     your legs in shape, test your gearing, and prepare for 
     what's to come.
  </p>

  <h2>Day 2</h2>
  <p>Day 2 starts with a climb up Bear Creek Canyon to Lookout 
     Mountain, followed by a swift and winding descent into the 
     town of Golden. Refresh yourself at the famous Coors Brewery. 
  </p>

  <h2>Day 3</h2>
  <p>Day 3 takes you along the Peak to Peak Highway. This 
     55-mile route showcases the mountains of the Front Range, 
     providing amazing vistas from Golden Gate Canyon State Park 
     to Rocky Mountain National Park.
  </p>  

  <h2>Day 4</h2>
  <p>Now for the supreme challenge: Day 4 brings some real 
     high-altitude cycling through Rocky Mountain National Park 
     and up Trail Ridge Road. It's an amazing ride, high above 
     timberline, topping out at over 11,000 feet.
  </p>

  <h2>Day 5</h2>
  <p>We start Day 5 on the west side of the Continental Divide. 
     From Grand Lake, you'll bike to Winter Park and then over 
     Berthoud Pass, and back to the eastern side of 
     the Continental Divide.
  </p>

  <h2>Day 6</h2>
  <p>On Day 6, we ride 
     back to Littleton over Squaw Pass and Bear Creek and then
     enjoy a celebratory dinner as we share memories of a great
     tour.
  </p>
   </aside>
```

What am i missing? Thanks!!

Comment: could you include your html?

Comment: @JeremyLucas added it. thanks

Comment: Your css targets things inside your `aside`, but your `h1` is outside. The rest looks fine

Answer (score 1):

```css
aside#tour_itinerary h1 {font-size: 1.2em;}

aside#tour_itinerary h2 {font-size: 0.9em;}

aside#tour_itinerary p {font-size: 0.8em;}
```

```html
<body>
<aside id="tour_itinerary">
  <header>
    <h1>Itinerary</h1>
 </header>
    <h2>Day 1</h2>
    <p>We start from the foothills above Littleton, Colorado, 
        promptly at 9am. The first day is a chance to get 
        your legs in shape, test your gearing, and prepare for 
        what's to come.
    </p>
    <h2>Day 2</h2>
    <p>Day 2 starts with a climb up Bear Creek Canyon to Lookout 
        Mountain, followed by a swift and winding descent into the 
        town of Golden. Refresh yourself at the famous Coors Brewery. 
    </p>
    <h2>Day 3</h2>
    <p>Day 3 takes you along the Peak to Peak Highway. This 
        55-mile route showcases the mountains of the Front Range, 
        providing amazing vistas from Golden Gate Canyon State Park 
        to Rocky Mountain National Park.
    </p>  
    <h2>Day 4</h2>
    <p>Now for the supreme challenge: Day 4 brings some real 
        high-altitude cycling through Rocky Mountain National Park 
        and up Trail Ridge Road. It's an amazing ride, high above 
        timberline, topping out at over 11,000 feet.
    </p>
    <h2>Day 5</h2>
    <p>We start Day 5 on the west side of the Continental Divide. 
        From Grand Lake, you'll bike to Winter Park and then over 
        Berthoud Pass, and back to the eastern side of 
        the Continental Divide.
    </p>
    <h2>Day 6</h2>
    <p>On Day 6, we ride 
        back to Littleton over Squaw Pass and Bear Creek and then
        enjoy a celebratory dinner as we share memories of a great
        tour.
    </p>
</aside>  
</body>
```

Looks like you're missing the aside tag, as well as the ID in the tag. This could be fixed by wrapping the content you're wanting with the following tag:

```
<aside id="tour_itinerary">
...content here ...
</aside>
```

Based on the html given and the description, you would put the `<aside id="tour_itinerary">` above the `<header>` or beneath the `</header>`. Then the `</aside>` below the very last `</p>`

Comment: thanks - i edited my code in my original question and now  i think it reflects your suggested changes, but it still doesn't work. Can you please take another look and see if there's anything else i can change to make it work? i appreciate it

Comment: Could you let me know which portion isn't working? I have a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/bGGzrYV), seems to be working alright